# How is it possible that Maeve can control Bernard?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

** SPOILER warning for anyone who hasn't watched the whole first season of Westworld **

In the later episodes of *Westworld,* we find out that Bernard is in fact a host created in the image of Arnold. We see Ford controlling Bernard via voice commands. From the first episode we have seen hosts being controlled through voice commands by everyone in westworld administration, be it Developers or QA or techs. But since no one has ever found out that Bernard is a host suggests that to control Bernard, some special privileged access might be required. Perhaps only Ford could control him using the voice commands. This could be possible seeing how Ford knows no one else would ever need to control Bernard and doing so also ensures the secrecy of Bernard's true nature.

The following episode depicts Maeve controlling Bernard as well. It's curious as to why Ford would ever allow someone else an access high enough that they could control Bernard. Perhaps Maeve may have received a high access level when she updated herself. It's peculiar as to why Ford would allow something like that to be possible.  Basically controlling Bernard should require 'God' access level.

Another point could be made that Ford allowed that to help her escape, but she didn't need Bernard's help. Whatever the techs changed seemed to be enough to let her escape. **So how could Maeve control Bernard ?**

Comment: I think Ford programmed him to respond to a Maeve because he knew she might be under his scrutiny.... that's what I told myself anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Episode 8, "Trace Decay", Maeve coerces Felix to adjust her settings to make her influential to the maximum degree. It can be assumed that Bernard is custom programmed so he will only obey overriding orders from someone with complete influence, with the only individual thus far being Dr. Ford. However, the re-programming given to Maeve in Episode 8 is implied to give her enough footing that she is second only to Dr. Ford. The reason I say "second", by the way, is that she still is programmed to escape the park, so she is not in complete control-- unlike him.

Comment: I think that while she was "improved", guys there didn't have that much authority and it was Ford who secretly upgraded her access that high, along with giving her incentive to go on a mission abroad.